# PHP or MySQL stored procedure for a tree with five nodes (PentTree)

Tags: php, tree, treeview, traversal

I wish to build an MLM project. Every member can have 5 members at its nodes. And we will be having 6 levels deep for every members.

Here is the table I am using:

```
(id, name, parent_id, level)
```

Before inserting any member, I need to check from this member to all the way top to main root node, that whose level is going to complete after inserting this member. (Need PHP function with queries, or MySQL stored procedure to check and update the levels of every parent node).

Then I also need to have a PHP function or MySQL stored procedure which can give me the details from a node all the way to bottom of it and can also print the tree from this node to all the way to bottom.

Comment: homework is really getting weird these days.

Comment: @shairoo, this is far too broad a question for any technical assistance site. It is basically "I'm building a website, please give me the code". The whole point of programming is you find it yourself (a library) or build it yourself.

Comment: (You may be interested in the "nested set" algorithm, which can be implemented in MySQL and PHP. Do a web search for it, and you should find something).

Comment: I only asked 2 functions one for traverse to down and other to top.  no full fledged website :) @halfer

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid asking for ready made code isn't really how this site works. We generally like to see that you've tried to solve the problem on your own (though occasionally someone will help you anyway). For example, did you [do a search for this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+tree+mysql)? In those results, a cursory look reveals at least two helpful and relevant posts, both with code.

Comment: Actually I have researched and home worked on it , but everyone has talked about binary trees, I need to implement on a tree with 5 nodes and also with database in mysql.  many of the members has asked similar question here but here is no suitable answer. @halfer

Comment: Well, do please put all your research in the question (that will help it to stay open). From your brief requirements I would be reasonably sure a nested set implementation would do what you want.